# Conditional execution of a PHP script to send email

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to create a form page which validates the contents and if validation is true displays an alert box and then, sends the data to an email address. the problem is that the validation and alert box functions are working fine, am just unable to incorporate php script to send email to my email id... Any help will be appreciated .. My code is

```
<form action = "javascript:myFunc()" && onsubmit="return validateForm()" 
      method = "post" class="sigPad" 
      style = "width:100%; text-align:center;" name = "myForm">`
```

Where `myFunc` is as under:

```
`function myFunction() {
    alert("text here");
window.open(
'https://mywebsite.com','_blank');}
```

Just help me in including php script to send email which runs only if the `validateForm()` function and `myFunction()` are both executed.

Comment: This question has nothing at all to do with neither Java nor JScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `action` attribute of your form (assuming the `&&` is just a typo...):

```
<form action="/path/to/your/script.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" class="sigPad" style="width:100%; text-align:center;" name="myForm">
```

Now the form will only be submitted when `validateForm()` returns `true`.

Unless javascript is disabled of course, then it will always submit.

Comment: thnks buddy.. is working now.. need to do some more work on the code

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind if you use javascript for validation spammers can still get around your validation. It's front end validation so anyone can manipulate it.

You should use php to validate. One php file can validate and then send the email. Here is a simple tutorial for validation: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp The guide also uses regular expressions to help validate emails are in correct format. This can also be done for phone numbers and zip codes.

You can also set up Captcha with php as your backend help prevent spammers as well. https://www.phpcaptcha.org/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **&&** from your code and action should refer to a php script you can do your validation in a javascript function which can also be used to display alerts.
for example

```
<form action= "yourphpscript.php()" onsubmit="validateForm()" method="post" class="sigPad" style="width:100%; text-align:center;" name="myForm">`
```

validateForm() could be used for your validation logic and displaying the alert